# How to create skewed lines with CSS?

Tags: css, transform

I'm trying to draw 4 parallel lines with CSS. I'm using skew feature of css to play with these lines angles. But it is not working as I expected, I need more spaces between the lines. Should I handle it with only using CSS and transform?

```css
.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.line.line-1 {
  top: 100px;
  transform: skewY(20deg);
}

.line.line-2 {
  top: 150px;
  transform: skewY(28deg);
}

.line.line-3 {
  top: 200px;
  transform: skewY(35deg);
}

.line.line-4 {
  top: 250px;
  transform: skewY(41deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="line line-1"></div>
  <div class="line line-2"></div>
  <div class="line line-3"></div>
  <div class="line line-4"></div>
</div>
```

This is the background that I want to implement:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use transform rotate, set the origin to left and repositionate it to the origin point on the page.

```css
.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: left;
  
  
  left: 100px;
  top: 0;
}
.line.line-1 {
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}
.line.line-2 {
  transform: rotate(40deg);
}
.line.line-3 {
  transform: rotate(70deg);
}
.line.line-4 {
  transform: rotate(105deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="line line-1"></div>
    <div class="line line-2"></div>
    <div class="line line-3"></div>
  <div class="line line-4"></div>
</div>
```